# Find the angle using vectors

Tags: vectors

Given four non zero vectors $\vec a,\vec b, \vec c$ and $\vec d$. The vectors $\vec a,\vec b$ and $\vec c$ are coplanar but not collinear pair by pair and $\vec d$ is not coplanar with vectors $\vec a,\vec b$ and $\vec c$ and $\widehat{(\vec a\; \vec b)}=\widehat{(\vec b\, \vec c)}=π/3$, $\widehat{(\vec d\;\vec a)}=m$ and $\widehat{(\vec d\; \vec b)}= n$, prove that $\widehat{(\vec d\; \vec c)}=cos^{-1} (cos\,n- cos\,m) $.

I am not getting any start how to do it , can anybody help me in this.

Comment: This can't be right. I suspect that you made a typo

Comment: I suppose that $n$ is the angle between $c$ and $d$.

Comment: @polfosol this is the original question http://i.imgur.com/XMvjH8C.jpg

Comment: @zoli no it is the angle between b and d . And we have to find out angle between c and d

Comment: @koolman Image was not found (Error 404)

Comment: @polfosol that is working

Comment: https://s23.postimg.org/ha4g37u17/Screenshot_2017_01_21_16_52_38_1.jpg

Comment: Than no need for $-1$ in exponentation in second and third cosines.

Comment: @kolobokish oh sorry

Comment: See what means that $ab$ and $bc$ form angles with magnitude $\frac{\pi}{3}$. $ca$ also have angle $\frac{\pi}{3}$. (equilateral triangle.)

Comment: @kolobokish then what to do next

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $\hat a, \hat b, \hat c$ be unit vectors along $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$ respectively and $\widehat{(\vec d\;\vec c)}=\theta$.

$$\begin{align}
\therefore\qquad\hat a+\hat c&=\hat b\\
 \vec d. \hat a+\vec d.\hat c&=\vec d. \hat b\\
 |\vec d||\hat a|\cos\,m+|\vec d||\hat c|\cos\,\theta&=|\vec d||\hat b|\cos\,n\\
\theta&=\cos^{-1}(\cos\,n-\cos\, m) 
\end{align}$$